# Visual Studio 11 seems to ignore the [shift] key in certain contexts?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

A percentage of the times that I create an instance of an object, my shift key is disabled for the next keypress.

I try to type:

```
ClassName thing = new ClassName()
```

but it comes out:

```
ClassName thing = new ClassName9)
```

My best guess is that there is some kind of hotkey or macro that VS is attempting to use here, but I can't seem to figure out which. I've verified that this is a VS 11 issue by attempting the same keystrokes in other applications with no unusual behavior. Also, I'm not typing too fast. I'm being very deliberate in my keystrokes. Does anyone have an idea of what's going on or how to fix this?

Comment: Is there a VS2011 version? If you can confirm its a VS 2010 or the latest 2012 we can probably look more into it. Any service packs installed? vs2010 sp1 creates small issues sometimes

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio 11 Version 11.0.50323.1 QRELB

Comment: There is no Visual Studio 2011 - There is a VS 11 Beta at present, but when it's released, it will *not* be called Visual Studio 2011.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it still repro in safe mode?  If not it's an Add-in doing the damage.  If it still repro's I'd be tempted to reinstall VS.

```
DevEnv /safemode
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms241278(v=vs.80).aspx

VS CommandLine Switch Docs

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7(v=VS.80).aspx

Comment: I'm still getting the issue in safemode. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: No problem - some other thoughts from one our forums...
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vseditor/thread/a189ec4d-3910-4607-bf6d-618846904f2d

I'd be tempted to create a new user account and see if it repros there first before starting to blow away settings with ResetSettings etc.

Comment: @Divegato Why did you accept this answer if it doesn't answer your question?